# Typescript is not detecting errors for nonexistent type names in declaration "d.ts" files

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, tsconfig

In this [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEA7KBbEBnADlMCDKA8gLICiA+gHICCpeAClQMInwDeAUPF-AJaIAuIGADMc+YuQCSFACokASgDEmLDt3XxMMAPaYqALniFSZGQE06JTtwC+7G0A) in Typescript playground I'm trying to use an **nonexistent type** inside a namespace and I get an error:

[image]

[image]

This is expected.

But in my local dev environment, Typescript is basically accepting any nonexistent type as `any`.

**Note:** This is only happening inside `d.ts` files.

[image]

[image]

Don't know if it matters, but I'm using the `noImplicitAny: true` flag.

See my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": ["./src/*"],
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "functions/src/**/*",
    "functions/index.ts"
  ],
}
```

How can I make Typescript detect those errors?

Comment: Is that a `.d.ts` file?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes, it is. Sorry, I forgot to mention that. Will add it to the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Declaration files, files with a `.d.ts` extension, are covered by the `--skipLibCheck` compiler option.

By specifying

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

in your `tsconfig.json`, you have told TypeScript not to validate this file.

Broadly speaking, you have two options to enforce validation of this file.

1. Rename the file from `.d.ts` to `.ts`. This is the most direct approach, and the least invasive. `.ts` files that contains only declarations are perfectly valid.
2. Remove the `"skipLibCheck": true` configuration above thereby enforcing type checking in `.d.ts` files which is the default behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that information. I get this warning when I convert the file to `ts`: _ES2015 module syntax is preferred over custom TypeScript modules and namespaces._. I will see if I can disable the `"skipLibCheck": true`. I activated it because `@types/styled-components` was triggering lots of type conflicts.

Comment: It's hard to tell based on that error because I can't see the whole file. You should avoid writing `declare module "module_specifier" {}` in any context other than module augmentation because it pollutes the global declaration space. If you can point me at that file, I might be able to give you a pointer.

Comment: Here is my intent: I would like my project types to be accessible throughout all of my source files without having to import them. For example on `test.ts`, I'd like to do `const foo: MY_PROJECT_TYPES.FOO` and it works. The way I've found out how to do that is by using `declare namespace` on `d.ts` files. Considering the warning I got when I converted to `.ts` files, it seems that this is not recommended outside `d.ts` files. What is the best practice for this pattern? Thanks!

Comment: It is not recommended inside `.d.ts` files either. **_Note_** that it isn't `declare namespace` that is to be avoided, but **_globals_**.  It's a complex topic I can't cover in a comment, but what you see in various third party declarations is only global when the file isn't a module (no top-level `import` or `export` anywhere in it). I will say that I believe your intent is problematic and this has nothing to do with `.d.ts` vs `.ts`. You shouldn't pollute the global namespace, with types or values, and the conflicts that compelled you to set `--skipLibCheck` are evidence of why.